# Problem with using makefile variables in conditionals

Tags: makefile

I have a makefile where I would like to append values to a makefile variable in case of e.g specific os version (the following snippet isn't part of any target in my makefile):

```
required_packages = x y 
debian_version = `(cut -d. -f1 < /etc/debian_version)`
ifeq ($(debian_version),9) 
        required_packages := $(required_packages) z
endif
```

The content of my `/etc/debian_version` is `9.9` and the condition above evaluates to false so the appending doesn't happen and I am not sure why. I am pretty new to make and it could be that something very obvious is wrong here.

I have tried quoting the number in the condition - "9" - but that doesn't work a well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make is not shell, backticks are not supported.

Use `($shell ...)` function instead. Also, use `:=` to make sure it's called once.

```
debian_version := $(shell cut -d. -f1 < debian_version)
```